# What are the dimensions of the book?

Tags: triangles, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, pythagorean-triples

[image: B]

There are five copies of a book each 20mm thick. When tilted, they fit snugly inside a cubic box with a gap of 16mm at the bottom left as shown.

I struggled with this in a recent practice paper, any help appreciated.

Comment: Try [here](https://www.quora.com/Aside-Romel-has-5-copies-of-a-large-book-Each-book-is-20mm-thick-When-tilted-they-fit-snugly-inside-a-cubic-box-with-gap-16mm-at-the-bottom-left-as-shown-What-are-the-dimensions-of-the-book) where the same question was posed and answered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The triangles are all similar to one another, all of them to the (12,16,20) right angles triangle. So, assuming cubic box of side $a$, we have the triangle (12,16,20) is similar to the triangle ($a-80$, $a-12$, $l$) formed by the book's surface and two perpendicular edges

Hence

$$\frac{a-80}{a-12} = \frac{3}{4}$$

That will give you $a$ as well as the book dimensions

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know the gap between each book is 16mm? We only know the gap between the first one is 16mm.

Comment: And what is the proof that they are similar?

Comment: So one is that the book surfaces are parallel to one another, that means all the angles will be the same, plus since each book has same thickness and the small triangles are similar, then they must be congruent (AAS)